# Did Lucy ever recover her consciousness?

Tags: elfen-lied

In the manga, Kaede ("Lucy/Nyu")

> lost her Lucy consciousness ("bad side" or "little Kaede" side) and kept the Nyu consciousness.

Did she ever recover her Lucy or "real" side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before Lucy's body completely melted away and was about to be shot in the head, she went berserk. So it is safe to say that she indeed *recovered* her evil side. Although on the other hand, we could see her DNA protect Kouta unconsciously, so the memories she made after becoming "Lucy" were real, and despite recovering her true self, she could not forget about those happy memories she had with Kouta and the others.

[image]

Comment: What's the manga chapter when this occurs?

Comment: @LucasHenrique Chapter 106.